# How to use python requests to get all cookie values

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I can only get a part of the value of coookies with requests, there is no way to get all the cookie values.But I can get all cookie values ​​using selenium.[selenium_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXFs7.png)
[requests_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAYCZ.png)[requests_cookie_get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2qmz.png)[all_cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhJyc.png)[selenium_cookie_get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr0lt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use requests.Session and observe cookies before and after a request:

```
import requests
   >>>
   session = requests.Session() >>>
   print(session.cookies.get_dict()) {} >>>
   response = session.get('http://google.com') >>>
   print(session.cookies.get_dict()) {
      'PREF': 'ID=5514c728c9215a9a:FF=0:TM=1406958091:LM=1406958091:S=KfAG0U9jYhrB0XNf',
      'NID': '67=TVMYiq2wLMNvJi5SiaONeIQVNqxSc2RAwVrCnuYgTQYAHIZAGESHHPL0xsyM9EMpluLDQgaj3db_V37NjvshV-eoQdA8u43M8UwHMqZdL-S2gjho8j0-Fe1XuH5wYr9v'
   }
```

If you need the path and thedomain for each cookie, which get_dict() is not exposes, you can parse the cookies manually, for instance:

```
[{
      'name': c.name,
      'value': c.value,
      'domain': c.domain,
      'path': c.path
   }
   for c in session.cookies
]
```